# SQL averaging columns by category

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the average of a column, based on another column. Then, I'd like to create a new column where that average stands in for each category.
I can't seem to figure this out. Thanks for any help.

Here's my table

```
| value   |  category  |
|    3    |      a     |
|    4    |      a     |
|    5    |      a     |
|    2    |      b     |
|    4    |      b     |
|    3    |      b     |
|    1    |      c     |
|    7    |      c     |
```

And here's what I want:

```
| value   |  category  |  category avg  |
|    3    |      a     |         4      |
|    4    |      a     |         4      |
|    5    |      a     |         4      |    
|    2    |      b     |         3      |
|    4    |      b     |         3      |
|    3    |      b     |         3      |    
|    1    |      c     |         4      | 
|    7    |      c     |         4      |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a subquery, either in the `from` clause or the `select` clause.  Here is one way:

```
select value, category,
       (select avg(value) from table t2 where t.category = t2.category) as catgory_avg
from table t;
```

EDIT:

If you want to *update* the value in the table, then you can do:

```
update table t join
       (select category, avg(value) as avgv
        from table t
        group by category
       ) tavg
       on t.category = tavg.category
    t.category_avg = tavg.avgv;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confused because I only have one table. I've created a blank column for 'Category Avg' where that calculation should go. Is that possible?

Comment: @bdkauff And so does the example above ;-)

Comment: The subquery references the same table as the main query, but with t2 as the alias rather than t. The result will be accurate, but inefficient as the subqury will be calculated once per row of table.

Comment: @JoeMurray . . . With an index on `category, value`, performance should be pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

per your comment it looks like you are wanting to update the table with the average of the value. this can be done with an update and a select like so

```
UPDATE table t,
(   SELECT AVG(value) as avg_val, category 
    FROM table
    GROUP BY category
) r
SET t.category_avg = r.avg_val
WHERE t.category = r.category
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7fd6/1)

Comment: Thanks! What is r, then? Sorry I'm not very familiar with sql.

Comment: @bdkauff r is the alias to the select so you can reference it in the SET and WHERE